# Show that $||x| - |y|| \le |x-y|$ for all $x, y, \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Show that $||x| - |y|| \le |x-y|$ for all $x, y, \in \mathbb{R}$

**Working:**

So we know that $|x| = |(x-y) + y | \le |x-y|+|y|$

Thus, $|x|-|y| \le |x-y| \ \cdots (1)$ and similarly, $|y|-|x| = -(|x|-|y|) \le |x-y| \ \cdots (2)$.

We also know that $||x|-|y|| =   \begin{cases} |x|-|y| \ \text{if} \ |x| - |y| \ge 0 \\ -(|x| - |y|) \ \text{if} \ |x| - |y| < 0 \end{cases}$

**Query:**

I'm not exactly sure how to finish off the proof. Can I say because $(1)$ and $(2)$ are both true, then $||x| - |y|| \le |x-y|$ as required?

Comment: Yes, you can say that.

Comment: You can also use the fact that $|u| < a \Leftrightarrow -a < u < a$.

Comment: $||x|-|y||\le|x-y|\Leftrightarrow||y|-|x||\le|y-x|$ so you can assume that for example in your case $|x|>|y|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. If you are unsure, you can divide the proof in two cases: $|x|-|y|<0$ or $|x|-|y| \geq 0$. You can prove the inequality in both cases and these cases contain all possibilities, so you have proved the inequality in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$|x|=|x-y+y|\leq |x-y|+|y|, $$
then
$$|x|-|y|\leq |x-y| .$$
Analogously,

$$|y|=|y-x+x|\leq |y-x|+|x|=|-1(x-y)|+|x|=|x-y|+|x|\Rightarrow |y|-|x|\leq |x-y|, $$
i.e.,
$$-(|x|-|y|)\leq |x-y|. $$

Now, as for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$, $|a|=\max\{-a,a\}$, we have
$$||x|-|y||=\max\{-(|x|-|y|),|x|-|y|\}\leq |x-y|, $$
in other words,
$$||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|. $$